# $\cosh(z) := \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^{2k}}{(2k)!}, z \in \mathbb{C}$ and $\cosh(z) = \frac{1}{2} (\exp(z)+\exp(-z))$

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series, exponential-function

Let $\cosh$ be given by

$$\cosh(z) := \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^{2k}}{(2k)!}, z \in \mathbb{C}$$

How can one show that the power series converges absolutely for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$?

I also have to show that

$$\cosh(z) = \frac{1}{2} (\exp(z)+\exp(-z))$$

When using the ratio test I get

$$\left|\frac{(2k)!}{(2k+1)!} \frac{z^{2k+1}}{z^{2k}}\right| = \frac{|z|}{k+1} \Rightarrow 0 \text{ (n} \to \infty)  < 1 \text{ for all }z \Rightarrow r = \infty$$ (while $r$ is the convergence radius). So, the power series converges absolutely for all $z$.
Is this correct?

Regarding $$\cosh(z) = \frac{1}{2} (\exp(z)+\exp(-z))$$ I have that,

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{z^k}{k!} + \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^kz^k}{k!}\right) &=& \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(1 -(-1)^k)z^k}{k!} \\
&=& \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(1 -(-1)^{2k})z^{2k}}{(2k)!} + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(1 -(-1)^{2k})z^{2k}}{(2k+1)!} \\
&=& 0 + \frac{2}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{z^{2k}}{(2k+1)!}\\
&=& \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{z^{2k}}{(2k+1)!}
\end{eqnarray}

Is that correct?

Comment: There's an error for the ratio text: you should consider $\;\biggl|\dfrac{(2k)!}{(2k+2)!} \,\dfrac{z^{2k+2}}{z^{2k}}\biggr|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first step you changed $1+(-1)^{k}$ to $1-(-1)^{k}$ and that is why you are getting a wrong answer.